# Как загрузить ресурсы книги "Изучаем Python" Эрика Мэтиза?

Tags: python

Не знаю как загрузить ресурсы книги "Изучаем Python" Эрика Метиза. В книге написано загружать ресурсы по адресу https://www.nostarch.com/pythoncrashcourse2e/, но на этом сайте нет кнопки чтобы чего либо скачать. Мне нужно скачать файл sitka_weather_07-2018_simple.csv.

Нашёл сайт https://github.com/ehmatthes/pcc_2e/blob/master/chapter_16/the_csv_file_format/data/sitka_weather_07-2018_simple.csv, но там есть только кнопка перейти к файлу, а скачать его нельзя.

На код приведённый ниже выдаёт ошибку:

> Module Not Found Error.

```
import csv

file_name = 'sitka_weather_2018_simple.csv'
with open(file_name) as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    header_row = next(reader)
    print(header_row)
```

Если кто-нибудь знает где загрузить ресурсы книги то пожалуйста напишите. Заранее спасибо!

Comment: https://ehmatthes.github.io/pcc/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Перейдите по ссылке https://ehmatthes.github.io/pcc_2e/regular_index/ и нажмите кнопку "Download .zip". В загрузившемся .zip архиве должен быть файл `chapter_16/the_csv_file_format/data/sitka_weather_07-2018_simple.csv`.

Answer (score 0):

Если хочешь скачать архив с GitHub. То переходишь по ссылке https://github.com/ehmatthes/pcc
Далее жмёшь зелёную кнопку **Code** >> **Download ZIP**  https://prnt.sc/ef77HfAUiGfi

Для того, чтобы полноценно работать с гит и загружать напрямую в IDE нужно установить сам git и познакомиться с GitHub. Для базового понимания будет достаточно https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zZBiln_2FhM